# SH404 for SetRedirect url from controller in joomla

Tags: joomla1.5

I am writing a custom sh404 file for a custom component in joomla. I have written some of the redirecting urls by using setRedirect function. But it is not redirecting to SH404 URL.

What I have given is:

$link = JURI::base().'index.php?option=com_camassistant&controller=rfp&task=editrfp&var=copy&rfpid='.$insert_id.'&Itemid='.$_REQUEST['Itemid'] ;
$this->setRedirect( $link,$msg );

Can you please say how can I give $link to change SH404 automatically?

Thanks in advance 
Sateesh

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get it properly.

If you do something like:
JError::raiseError(404, 'Not Found');